# Bitlocker password includes £ symbol (pound sterling)

Tags: passwords, bitlocker

I have changed the BitLocker password; the new one includes the character '£'. This cannot easily be typed; what keystrokes can generate this character please?

Comment: Operating system? System language?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably hold alt+0163 to get -> '**£**'

I'm assuming this is an English Windows OS since you mention BitLocker